# Problem creating an Embedded Jetty Endpoint in a NetBeans Platform Application using System.setProperty

Tags: java, netbeans, jax-ws, endpoint, embedded-jetty

I created a Netbeans Platform Application using Netbeans 7.0.1 and the JDK 1.7.

I implemented my own Web Application on a normal module using Embedded Jetty 7.4.5 (consisting of a Web Service and a couple of servlets), and I created a Library Wrapper Module including all the Jetty jar files and the "jetty-j2sehttpspi-7.4.5.v20110725.jar" that I needed to be able to publish the Web Service's Endpoint. The Web module has a dependency on the Jetty module.

The code I'm using is this:

```java
System.setProperty("com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerProvider",
   "org.mortbay.jetty.j2sehttpspi.JettyHttpServerProvider");

server = new Server();
JettyHttpServerProvider.setServer(server);

//We read the config file
String[] configFiles = {"etc/jetty.xml"};
for(String configFile : configFiles) {
   XmlConfiguration configuration =
      new XmlConfiguration(new File(configFile).toURI().toURL()); 
   configuration.configure(server);
}

// Web Services
QueryWeb qWS = new QueryWeb();
Endpoint.publish("http://0.0.0.0:" +
    (server.getConnectors()[0].getPort()) + "/ws", qWS);

// Servlets
HandlerCollection hc = (HandlerCollection)server.getHandler();
ServletContextHandler sch =
    new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
sch.setContextPath("/web");
sch.addServlet(stream.class, "/stream");
// We add the servlet handler to the server's context handler collection
// because it's the one used by the Web Service Endpoint
ContextHandlerCollection chc = (ContextHandlerCollection)hc.getHandlers()[0];
chc.addHandler(sch);

server.start();
```

When I try and run the application, I get the following error after the "Endpoint.publish" call:

```
Exiting C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.0\harness\run.xml.
Exiting C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.0\harness\run.xml.
C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.0\harness\suite.xml:500:
    The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.0\harness\run.xml:225:
    The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.0\harness\run.xml:193:
    The application is already running within the test user directory.
    You must shut it down before trying to run it again.
```

As far as I understand, this is happening because the system can't find the "org.mortbay.jetty.j2sehttpspi.JettyHttpServerProvider" class. Therefore it defaults back to the web server included in the JDK, which causes a conflict since we get both web Servers (Jetty and the JDK's) trying to run on the same port (in this case it's 8081).

The only way I managed to fix this problem was by copying all the Jetty jar files into the JRE's "lib/ext" folder (copying only the "jetty-j2sehttpspi-7.4.5.v20110725.jar" results in no errors, but the server won't start). In this way the system can find the class it needs and all it's dependencies.

I suppose that what's going on is that even if NetBeans uses it's own classpath loader, the System.setProperty method is ignoring this and trying to access the standard classpath, and since a NetBeans Platform Application doesn't actually let you change the classpath directly (that would beat the whole purpose of having modules administered by the NetBeans platform), I don't really know how to make it use the library included in the wrapper module.

I can keep developing the application with the temporary solution I found, but honestly, copying stuff into the JRE folders is not an acceptable solution and will eventually result in distribution and installation problems in client machines (already tried it in a Mac OS machine and I didn't even know where the JRE kept it's libraries to try and do the same dirty trick).

Therefore I want to ask you guys if there is any solution to this particular problem or if anyone has a better explanation of what's going on and how I might fix it without having to recreate the whole architecture of my project (which actually works OK except for this little inconvenient).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Write your question to the mailing list, dev@platform.netbeans.org, and you're more likely to get an answer.